# Automatically set KeystoneJS uploaded file URL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, keystonejs

How would I automatically set the URL on an uploaded File in Keystone.js? This is the model for the File:

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;

var FileUpload = new keystone.List('FileUpload');

var myStorage = new keystone.Storage({
  adapter: keystone.Storage.Adapters.FS,
  fs: {
    path: keystone.expandPath('./public/uploads/files'), // required; path where the files should be stored
    publicPath: '/public/uploads/files', // path where files will be served
  }
});

FileUpload.add({
  name: { type: Types.Key, index: true},
  file: {
    type: Types.File,
    storage: myStorage,
  },
  url: {type: String}
});


FileUpload.defaultColumns = 'name, url';
FileUpload.register();
```

I have tried to set the 'default' property of the url to something like

```
'/public/uploads/files/ + this.name
```

But the 'this' context is just an empty object literal. Keystone has an example in their docs where they make a custom frontend for uploading the images, and set the metadata of uploaded Files in a separate API call, but I'm trying to do this using their provided admin interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarification: you are trying make the entry in the Mongo database be the full path to the image not just the name of the image?

If I need something appended to the filename I do it on the template side, I guess you don't want to do that? Maybe if you explain the use case a little more?

Comment: I was trying to reference the file.filename in the model but I see now that it's just simpler to do it in the template. Thanks!